# Java Find Default Gateway IP (v4/v6), Windows/Linux/MAC for PCP

Tags: java, ipv6, nat, gateway, ipv4

I'm trying to implement fully-automatic PCP (according to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6887) for a decentralized P2P chat system.
That requires PCP configurations to be made, and so far I haven't found anyone having a library or framework for that. Now I'm trying to make my own, and here's the first hurdle:

How do I find the current system's Default Gateway IP on multiple OS types and if possible both IPv4 and IPv6.

I made myself a simple way of receiving and interpreting commands to the CLI of the host OS using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("[COMMAND LINE]");
```

as Java itself seems to provide no such information, of if I don't know where.
The current plan would involve getting the *ipconfig* and *ifconfig* returns on Windows and Linux (for MAC i'm sure there is a similar command), then search for the keyword of "gateway" and find the next IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, then see if anyone answers there on UDP port 5351 after a few attempts. I'm fairly certain it could work, but before using try-and-error methods I want to look for a more professional solution.

On top of that it would be good having a way to find out if the system is inside a NAT. While it usually isn't a problem with the private A, B and C networks there always is the possibility of custom settings on the router like more configured private networks requiring NAT.

Comment: https://github.com/libpcp/pcp ?

Comment: That would mean it has to be installed on the system its operating on I assume and require the user to manually install it or to create an installation routine before launching the client. But yeah, looks promising. Have you used it?

Comment: No. I just searched for a pcp library on google and that was my first hit

Comment: There is a server library as well

Comment: Explains it. I was looking for a Java library to include into the code so I didn't find it. But still, this seemingly has to be installed before the programm can run. If possible I'd like to have just the .jar file that opens without any other steps to be taken, but if it's not possible it's good the libpcp exists.